# How many cores do I get for Heroku dynos?

Tags: node.js, heroku

I launched a development node app on heroku with a free dyno. The app utilizes the cluster API, and when I run:

```
if (cluster.isMaster) {
    for (var i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
        // Create a worker
        console.log("Forking...");
        cluster.fork();
    } 
}
```

I end up with 8 workers. On [Heroku's docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dyno-types), there's an "Available Dyno Types" chart with a column labeled Compute(1) - is that CPU cores? If so, the free dyno has 1-4. Why is that a range? And why am I getting 8? Is there somewhere that lists exactly how many cores a given dyno has? I can't seem to find any reliable info.